# Can't use breakpoint in Visual Studio Code, with node (+babel) running in a docker container

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I can't use breakpoint in my VSCode, breakpoint stay "grey" with the message : "Unverified breakpoint".

See this capture : 
[image]

The debugger seems to be "connected", because I'm receiving logs from my program, and the bar is "orange". It's just impossible to use breakpoints.

About my configuration, here is what I use to configure the debugger :

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Test",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "address": "localhost",
  "port": 9230,
  "restart": true,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
  "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/",
  "outFiles" : [ "${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*.js" ],
  "smartStep": true
}
```

As you can see I use babel to compile my code from "${workspaceRoot}/src" -> "${workspaceRoot}/build".
I execute my code in a docker container, with a command "node inspect=0.0.0.0:9230 build/server.js"
I have some sourcemap in the build folder also.

I think the problem comes from the mapping between my local source and the remote build folder that is executed ... 
One time I got the breakpoint working but weirdly => breakpoint was active (red) but during execution the variables I got and the step by step was like the line was not the one executed ... 
During this test I change the config like this :

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Test",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "address": "localhost",
  "port": 9230,
  "restart": true,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
  "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/build",
  "outFiles" : [ "${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*.js" ],
  "smartStep": true
}
```

So right now I'm stuck, If you have any idea how to resolve the issue ?